# Highlight cells in an Excel column if the value can be found in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, highlight

I want to highlight all cells from column A if the value of the cell is found in columns B to E?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W670j.png)]

Every time an exact same value is entered in the arrange the value in column A should get highlighted

Answer (score 2):

`COUNTIFS()` should work.

```
=COUNTIFS(B:E,$A1)
```

[image]